# Truth/lie problem using Pigeonhole Principle

Tags: logic, pigeonhole-principle

In an island, there is only two kinds of inhabitants; knights who always tell the truth and knaves who always lie. You meet 3 inhabitants A, B, and C and have the following conversation with them. Uncover the nature of A, B, and C; that is, their identities.

**Case I:**

> A: "All three of us are knaves."
>
> B: "Exactly one of us is a knight."

**Case II:**

> You: "How many knights are among you?"
>
> A: "..."
>
> You: "What did A answer?"
>
> B: "A said that there is one knight among us."
>
> C: "B is lying."

I am not sure if this is a correct or valid way to approach the problem but I am trying to solve this problem using the Pigeonhole Principle.

This states that if a function $f$ maps two finite set $X\to Y$, and $\vert X\vert >\vert Y \vert $ then $f$ cannot be injective.

If I consider the set $X$ to contain the three inhabitants as its elements and $Y$ to be the set containing the type of inhabitants (knight, knave), then $3\gt2$ and $f$ is not injective.

The only missing part is a valid function that maps an inhabitant to a type of inhabitant and I would be able to determine which is which. Can such a function $f$ be deduced using this information?